# Preposition "In"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Why is there no preposition(to) before the word "afraid" in this quote?

> Sometimes the fear won’t go away, so you’ll have to do it afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To" or other prepositions wouldn't be appropriate inserted before an adjective like "afraid".

"To" would work before a *verb* like, for example, "succeed":

> Sometimes the fear won’t go away, but you’ll have to do it **to succeed**.

Some other preposition might work before a *noun* (maybe "fear"):

> Sometimes the fear won’t go away, so you’ll have to do **it in spite of
>   the fear**.

The sentence you quote is constructed in a slightly unusual way, but it is correct as it is. The adjective "afraid" modifies "you" (included in "you'll" = "you will"), and describes "you" during the time you will be "doing it."

The whole statement could be re-worded like this:

> Sometimes the fear won't go away, so you'll have to do it [when you
>   are] afraid.

It sounds clumsier that way, but the functioning of the words is easier to see.

The structure of the second clause is similar to these:

> He died happy.
>
> They grew up strong and healthy.
>
> He fell into bed exhausted.